# How to change the label text in default setting pages?

Tags: wp-admin, labels

I've seen various tutorials on how to modify the menu items of a Wordpress Site's admin, but I'm trying to find a tutorial or way on how to modify the actual admin page labels. Here's what I mean:

When you are in the back end and you hover over SETTINGS, and click GENERAL, a page comes up with, of course, the general settings for the site. The labels for each input field are as follows: SITE TITLE, TAGLINE, WORDPRESS ADDRESS(URL), SITE ADDRESS(URL), etc.

I'm looking to add a function to my functions.php for a theme that will allow me to change these labels

Is this even possible? Or do I just have to hard code it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the labels using `gettext` filter hook ex:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'theme_change_label_names');
function theme_change_label_names($translated_text){
    if (is_admin()){
        switch ( $translated_text ) {

            case 'Site Title' :

                $translated_text = __( 'New Site Title label', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;

            case 'Tagline' :

                $translated_text = __( 'new Tagline label', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;
        }

    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Comment: I was worried right off the bat when I read this solution that it wouldn't apply to the p.description directly under the input field for the site description, but "slap me silly and call me susan"....

Comment: Whatever you say Susan :)

Answer (score -1):

There are no [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters) applied to those labels, hence you cannot change it using a straight forward way. You may have to use a jQuery script for doing so. Don't hard code it, hard coding in core files is very bad!

The only things you can change in the General Settings page are the `date formats` and the `time formats`.

Comment: I kinda figured...

Comment: Yep! :D I think they should give a filter to change the labels and an action to add more fields to this page.

Comment: Not true at all!!!

Comment: Why so? I checked the core file `options-reading.php`. Is there some other way to do so? Did they add it in 3.4? Cuz I checked 3.1 or so...